# Vertical line required at the end of an interpolated curve

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python so please bear with me.
I am trying to recreate the power curve of a wind turbine.
I have a list of power output data per dV = 0.5 m/s.
I have interpolated the data to get the desired curve.
However, the original power curve has a cut out wind speed of 25 m/s, which results in a vertical line downwards. I have used the code below, but this generates a sloped line instead of a vertical one. 
I have also tried to do it with ax.step instead of ax.plot, which does generate a vertical line. 
But then the curve also turns into steps.

Is there any way I can generate the vertical line whilst keeping the interpolated curve?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg7T9.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

V_wind = np.arange(0, 30.5, 0.5)

P = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23.0, 68.0, 130.0, 206.0, 301.0, 418.0, 557.0, 720.0, 912.0, 1130.0, 1377.0, 1654.0, 1954.0, 2272.0, 2572.0, 2808.0, 2988.0, 3046.0, 3065.0, 3073.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 3075.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

P_turb = interp1d(V_wind, P, kind = 'linear')

fig, (ax) = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(V_wind, P_turb(V_wind))

ax.margins(0)
plt.ylim([0, 3500])
ax.set_title('Vestas V112 - 3.0MW Powercurve')
ax.set_xlabel('Wind speed [m/s]')
ax.set_ylabel('Power output [kW]')
ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib's `plot` function (which you call with the line `ax.plot(V_wind, P_turb(V_wind))` takes a bunch of consecutive (x, y) co-ordinates, and plots straight lines between them. Therefore, if you have a point at (24.5, 3075.0), and the next point is (25.0, 0.0), then you're going to have a strongly downward sloping line, but not an exactly vertical line.

To get an actual vertical line, you'll want to have two consecutive points *with the same horizontal co-ordinate*. For example, insert a point at (25.0, 3075.0), and follow that up with a point at (25.0, 0.0).

Also note that your interpolation isn't actually doing anything right now. It would only do something if you were to evaluate the interpolation (`P_turb(V_wind)`) at points *in between* the points on which the interpolation was made. Your code right now is equivalent to simply plotting `ax.plot(V_wind, P)`.